# Javascript regular expression to ignore blank lines/double spacing

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the regular expression:

```
var regex = /^\([A-Z])+\).+/g;
```

And when I run a `regex.test(paragraph)` where `paragraph` has the following:

> (A) Test
>
> (B) Testing
>
> (C) Tested

It snags on lines two and four because they are blank.  What I'd like to do is have the `.test()` return true under these circumstances, where there are blank lines.  Essentially, if there is anything at all on a line, it must start with at least one capital letter encased in parenthesis.

I attempted using an optional non-capturing group, but that also seemed to fail:

```
var regex = /^(?:\([A-Z]+\).+)?/g;
```

What kind of regular expression is needed to accomplish this, or am I better breaking up the `paragraph` variable with a `.split('\n')`, and looping through that to check?

Comment: **[this](https://regex101.com/r/iU0jC7/1)**

Comment: `/^(\([A-Z]+\).+)?$/gm` make sure to use `m` (MULTILINE) flag

Comment: Do not use `RegExp#test()` with a regex with `/g` modifier, remove it. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o0ez6ckL/1/).

Comment: Actually, I do not understand what you are trying to achieve, please clarify, best with a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will meet your requirements

```
^\([A-Z]+\)|^\s*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iU0jC7/1)**

*JS Demo*

```js
var re = /^(\([A-Z]+\).+)?$/gm; 
var str = '(A) Test\n\n(B) Testing\n\n(C) Tested';
var m = str.match(re);
document.writeln(m)
```